# Shell : store command in var for later use

Tags: bash, shell

For example:

```
CMD="ls /tmp/spaced\ dir"
```

And when using the command:

```
$ $CMD
ls: /tmp/spaced\: No such file or directory
ls: dir: No such file or directory
```

Not functional with:

```
CMD="ls /tmp/spaced\\ dir"
CMD="ls \"/tmp/spaced dir\""
CMD="ls \"/tmp/spaced\\ dir\""
CMD='ls \"/tmp/spaced dir\"'
```

And I need the parameter "`/tmp/spaced dir`" to be in a variable...
Of course, the directory "`/tmp/spaced dir`" does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found a solution using `eval`:

```
$ CMD="ls /tmp/spaced\\ dir/"
$ eval $CMD
dir_in_spaced_dir
$
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be talking about ALIAS

Set an Alias like this:

```
alias ls="ls /tmp/spaced"
```

And if you need the '/tmp/spaced' to be stored in a var, just do like this:

```
export MYVAR='/tmp/spaced'
alias cmd="ls ${MYVAR}"
```

If ALIAS not allowed, just put this in a FUNCTION

```
function mydir(){
    ls ${MYVAR}
}
```

Comment: Not an alias, this command may be only used in current script

Answer (score 1):

For bash, arrays are the way to go.

```
dir="/tmp/spaced dir"
CMD=( ls "$dir" )
echo "cmd has ${#CMD[@]} words"
"${CMD[@]}"  # execute the command
```